# Pause/ Sleep for n seconds in a Java EE environment

Tags: java, multithreading, jakarta-ee, thread-sleep, workmanagers

I have web application deployed on WebLogic. This web application has a servlet which tries to connect to a DB and if it fails it will wait/pause/sleep for some configured period of time and try to connect to the DB again. (Actually it will wait and try N times, exponentially, and if all the attempts fail, it will return a FAILURE response).

In order to wait/ pause between two attempts, I used

```
Thread.sleep();
```

But in the production environment where 8 weblogic managed servers are running, I found that Thread.sleep() is not reliable. It sleeps more than the configured time.

Is there any workaround for this?

Update:

Here's my code. Please note that I'm calling this from a managed server enlivenment.

```
public final void checkDBHealth() throws Throwable {

       for (int attempt=0; attempt<BACK_OFF_MAX_ATTEMPTS; attempt++) {
              try {
                     pauseExponentially(attempt);
                     connect();
                     execute();
                     close();
                     return;
              } catch (final Throwable th) {                 
                     if (ExceptionType.NON_RETRIABLE == ExceptionAnalyzer.translate(th) || (BACK_OFF_MAX_ATTEMPTS-1) == attempt) {
                            throw th;
                           // If exception is thrown I send the failure message
                     }
              }
       }

    }




  private void pauseExponentially(final int attempt) {
       if (attempt == 0) {
            return;
       }

        final long delay = (long) (((int)Math.pow(BACK_OFF_BASE, attempt)) * THOUSAND);
        try {
            Thread.sleep(delay);
        } catch (IE e) {…}

    }
```

Comment: Normally this should work, do you use it well ?
May be you should put part of your code in your question.

Comment: sleep is indeed not very accurate but should be accurate enough for this kind of stuff. How long do you want to sleep and how long is it sleeping?

Comment: You have a JEE Application and manage you databaseconnection yourself?  Lets the AppServer handle this by configuring a managed datasource.

Comment: I have posted my code. Could you please comment on this.

Answer (score 1):

Thread.sleep() ultimately makes a native operating system call.  The precision is limited by the OS itself.  Nothing the JVM can do about it.  Virtually all operating systems have a sleep-like syscall, and virtually all desktop/server OS's say something like, "sleep(n)" will block the calling process for *at least* n seconds/milliseconds/nanoseconds/whatever."  That is to say, they could block the caller for any amount of time that is longer than n.

There is a class of operating systems called Real-Time Operating Systems (RTOS) that make better guarantees than that.  If you really need precise control of the real-time behavior of your program, then you probably need to run it on an RTOS.